# CSS Horizontal distribution with dynamic contents

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have have some dynamically created divs in a fixed width parent div and I would like to have them distributed horizontally. As they are dynamically created so I wont know how many are in the container unless I count them with JS, which I am trying to avoid.

I was originally trying out the "**Using inline-block and justified text**" technique on [this](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) page; however it seems to behave a bit erracticly when there are more children than will fit ( ie when there are two rows ), ( see the second row [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ysvIg) ) so I don't think that will work.

****Edit:*** Actually I just realise now that it's not actually erratic, it IS spacing the second line correctly, but what I want instead (in this particular instance anyway ... ) is for the three red boxes on the second line to take up positions under the first three of the first line, leaving two positions free at the end, rather than spacing them out too ) .... so I think in general this technique is not likely to ever work for me.

Are there any suggestions of other ways to achieve the above. I would rather not have to use JS but if there is no other way then I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up conceding that I need to use JS. I added id's to the fourth child and then in CSS I was able to remove the margin from the fourth child ( all of this I presume could have been done in CSS using `nth child` if I hadn't needed IE8 support ).

**Edit:** Finally ended up getting what I want - http://jsfiddle.net/byronyasgur/kUgBA/14/

Answer (score 0):

It's not failing, that's the native behaviour of **floats**.

If you want more to fit per line, made the container bigger or the boxes narrower.

If you don't want them wrapping at all, add `overflow:auto` to your container's CSS and you'll get a scroll bar.

Comment: Sorry there's a misunderstanding, not sure how I put you on the wrong track ... I will try to revise my question ... but it's not that I dont want them wrapping, actually I do. The problem is that when I put in an extra one causing the wrap the layout seems to behave a bit erratically .... see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ysvIg

Comment: Using float:left instead of display:inline-block seems to fix this problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this. I am in the middle of a javascript solution so I think I will focus on that ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make remove the width of your container and add `display: inline-block;` to allow the dic container to have a width of whatever the content inside has. Also add `overflow: auto;` in order for the div to size to the amount of generated divs in it

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  background:olive;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: The containing div needs to have a fixed width. Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use relative widths rather than fixed widths for the interal divs....

```
#testcontainer div {
 width: 19%;
 height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
float: left;
margin: 2px;
```

}

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tlvbz)